# Proving Ratio of Errors = Ratio of Differences in Second Order sequences.

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson

I've been attempting to prove that the ratio of differences in the Newton-Raphson method which produces a a sequence of second order convergence, is equal to the ratio of Absolute Errors. A way of mathematically putting this could be as follows:
$$\frac{|AbsoluteError (x_{n+1})|}{(AbsoluteError(x_{n}))^2}\thickapprox k$$
as does,
$$\frac{|x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}|}{(x_{n+1}-x_{n})^2}\thickapprox k$$
where $k$ is a constant.

---

---

Proving this result for methods which produce a first order sequence where the denominators of the fractions are not raised to the power $2$, proves to be quite easy. The method I used to do this is as follows:

Let the Absolute Error in the approximation of the root at $x_n$ be equal to 
$\mathcal{E}$. This could be written as $|AbsoluteError(x_n)| = \mathcal{E}$

Since we know that $\frac{|AbsoluteError (x_{n+1})|}{(AbsoluteError(x_{n}))}\thickapprox k$, we can gather that $|AbsoluteError (x_{n+1})| = k\mathcal{E}$, and thus $|AbsoluteError (x_{n+2})| = k^2\mathcal{E}$ and so forth.

Using these results, we find that $|x_{n+1}-x_{n}| = \mathcal{E}-k\mathcal{E}$

and, $|x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}| = k\mathcal{E}-k^2\mathcal{E}$

Combining these gives us the following result:
$$\frac{|x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}|}{|x_{n+1}-x_{n}|}=k$$

The same result can be obtained from the Ratios of Differences in further terms, i.e. $\frac{x_{n+3}-x_{n+2}}{x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}} = k$

---

---

I am attempting to use this same method for proving the resut for second order sequences, and in doing so have derived the current relationships between terms:[image: Relationship between terms in 2nd order sequence]

I believe these relationships are true since when substituting them into the following expression I get the following results for all consecutive Errors in $x$:
$$\frac{|AbsoluteError(x_{n+1})|}{(AbsoluteError(x_n))^2} = \frac{k}{a}$$
which is a constant value.

However, when embarking on the same method I used for the first order converging sequences, I do not find consistency between 
$\frac{|x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}|}{(x_{n+1}-x_{n})^2}$ and $\frac{|x_{n+3}-x_{n+2}|}{(x_{n+2}-x_{n+1})^2}$

> Is there error in my methodology of tackling this problem, and if so could you provide an alternate proof to the original result I mentioned (Ratio of Differences = Ratio of Errors)?

Comment: You have an $X_x$ in your second equation. You meant $X_n$, correct?

Comment: Just corrected this to $x_n $